# C Linked nodes missing after function

Tags: c, huffman-code

Making a huffman tree from a text file. I'm new to the huffman concept so most of the code that I have is messy. The problem is that after creating the bottom nodes and linking them together as a tree ends up erasing the data in them. I'm not sure what is causing the missing data.

The main problem seems to be within the "*new_node*" and "*makeTree*" functions.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct node_t {
    struct node_t *left, *right;
    int freq;
    char data;
} node;

node* head;

int codes[128][2];
int sorted[128][2];
int nodeCount = 0;

char* concat(char* s1, char* s2){
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

node* new_node(char data, int freq, node* son1, node* son2){
    node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new != NULL){
        new->data = data;
        new->freq = freq;
        if(son1!= NULL && son2!= NULL){
            if((son1)->freq <= (son2)->freq){
                new->left = son1;
                new->right = son2;
            }
            if((son2)->freq > (son1)->freq){

                new->left = son2;
                new->right = son1;
            }
            printf("Data from children: %d, %d\n", son2->freq, son1->freq);
            new->freq = (son1)->freq + (son2)->freq;
        }
        else{
            new->left = NULL;
            new->right = NULL;
        }

    }
    printf("Created new node: Data: %c - Frequency: %d", new->data, new->freq);
    if(new->left != NULL){
        printf(" It has children\n");
    }
    else{
        printf(" Its a leaf.\n");
    }
    return new;
}

void print_code(node* headNode, char *code){
    if(headNode == NULL){
        return;
    }
    printf("Node: %d\n", headNode->freq);
    print_code(headNode->left, "");
}

void strtocode(char * str, int length){

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        int code = (int)str[i];
        if(code > 0 && code < 128){
            codes[code][0]++;
            if(codes[code][1] == 0){
                codes[code][1] = 1;
                nodeCount++;
            }
            //printf("%d : %d\n", str[i], codes[(int)str[i]][0]);
        }
    }
    //printf("Node Count: %d\n", nodeCount);
}

int findmin(){
    int min = 0;
    int id = -1;
    //printf("Searching for minimum value...\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        int freq = codes[i][0];
        if(codes[i][0] > 0 && codes[i][1]==1){
            if(min == 0){
                min = freq;
                id = i;
            }
            else{
                if(freq < min){
                    min = freq;
                    id = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(id!=-1){
        codes[id][1] = 2;
    }
    return id;
}

void sort_codes(){
    //printf("Sorting list...\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        if(i < nodeCount){
            int id = findmin();
            //printf("Id : %d\n", id);
            if(id != -1){
                sorted[i][0] = codes[id][0]; //Frecuencia
                sorted[i][1] = id;//Codigo ASCII
                //printf("%d : %d - %d\n", i, id ,sorted[i][0]);
            }
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
}

void init_codes(){
    for(int i = 0; i <128; i++){
        codes[i][0] = 0;
        codes[i][1] = 0;
    }
}

node* makeTree(){
    //No hay caracteres
    if(nodeCount == 0)
        return NULL;
    //Solo un nodo fue creado
    if(nodeCount == 1){
        node* one = new_node(sorted[0][1],sorted[0][0], NULL, NULL);
        return one;
    }
    //Mas de un nodo
    node * nodes[nodeCount];
    for(int i= 0; i<nodeCount; i++){
        nodes[i] = new_node(sorted[i][1],sorted[i][0],NULL,NULL);
    }
    int count = nodeCount;
    node* node1 = NULL;
    node* node2 = NULL;
    node* nodeJoin = NULL;

    do{
        int erased = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            if(node1 == NULL){
                node1 = nodes[i];
            }
            else if(node2 == NULL){
                node2 = nodes[i];
            }
            if(node1 != NULL && node2 != NULL){

                nodeJoin = new_node((char)0, 0, node1, node2);
                nodes[i] = nodeJoin;
                count--;
                erased++;
                //printf("Creating node from childs. Nodes left: %d. %d - %d,%d\n", count, i,node1->freq, node2->freq);
                nodes[i-1] = NULL;
                node1 = NULL;
                node2 = NULL;
            }
        }

        for(int a = 0; a < nodeCount - erased; a++){
            if(a == nodeCount - 1){
                break;
            }
            if(nodes[a]==NULL){
                int next = a+1;
                while(nodes[a] == NULL){
                    nodes[a] = nodes[next];
                    if(nodes[a] == NULL)
                        next++;
                }
                nodes[next] = NULL;
            }
        }
        node* sonTest = nodes[0]->left;
        printf("%d", sonTest->freq);
        if((count)==1){
            return nodes[0];
            //printf("Finalized with: Node %d\n", head->freq);
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    //printf("Tree is done\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE* fp;
    char * buffer = 0;
    long length;

    init_codes();
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp ==NULL){
        printf("File not found.\n");
    }
    else{
        fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (fp) + 1;
        fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc (length+1);
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            buffer[i] = fgetc(fp);
        }
        fclose (fp);
    }
    //printf("%ld\n%s\n", length, buffer);
    strtocode(buffer, length);
    //printf("Nodecount outside: %d\n", nodeCount);
    sort_codes();
    head = makeTree();
    printf("Head Node %d\n", head->freq);
    node* lefty = head->left;
    printf("Lefty Node %d\n", lefty->freq);
    //print_code(head,"");

    return 0;
}
```

As a huffman tree, the head node carries the total frequency of characters, that means that it takes the 2 frequencies of the child nodes (left & right). The problem here is that the head node does store the total frequency but the pointers to both child are NULL or pointing to crazy directions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might start with only a few values (5-10 instead of 255) for a start and run it in a debugger. Then you can see if and where your pointers are lost.

Comment: You don't check `next`, next can be bigger than `nodeCount`

Comment: Just use `valgrind` and you will highlight the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `node* new_node(char data, int freq, node* son1, node* son2)` works fine. There is a fallacy in `node* makeTree`.

I will try to explain with example. say the input file has text ***aabbccd***.

result of `void strtocode(char * str, int length)` will be very initial nodes with character, frequency of character and left and right pointers pointing to `null`.

```
|a, 2, null, null|, |b, 2, null, null|, |c, 2, null, null|, |d, 1, null, null|, |'\n', 1, null, null|
```

now `sort_codes()` does the sorting based on node count.

```
|'\n', 1, null, null|, |d, 1, null, null|, |a, 2, null, null|, |b, 1, null, null|, |c, 2, null, null|
```

now the `node* makeTree()` :

the nodeCount = 5 at this point. You created a nodes array with sorted data. let's analyze the first for loop inside do while. `for a value i = 0 node1` is having this `|'\n', 1, null, null|` then `for a value i = 1 node2` is having this `|d, 1, null, null|` . then `for a value i = 2` we have `node1` and `node2` pointing to valid nodes. now new node gets created you are assigning it to `nodes[2]` you lost the data at `nodes[2]` it was pointing to `|a, 2, null, null|` you no longer have that data. why?
.

why is first for loop running till nodeCount only? the final tree will have nodes around (nodeCount*(nodeCount+1))/2. again why?. There can be other issues as well. I got these for now.

Comment: I personally think that the only functions at problem here are the ones i mentioned. As far as your answer goes... when 2 nodes are join together, the new node is assigned to the node that detected that a join was possible, example: at i=0, node1 is assigned, at i=2 node2 is assigned and at the same time, a new node is created taking node1 and node2 as childs and then assigning the new node to `nodes[1]`. All nodes after address 1 are untoched. I suggest you try the code in some compiler like OnlineGDB

Answer (score 0):

So it seems i messed up with the validations, pretty much...
Something like

```
if(son1 <= son2){
    //something
}
if(son2 > son1){
    //something else
}
```

which are pretty much the same...